# When I try programmatically adding a UISlider to UIView, it wont appear if the width is too high

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, uislider

I'm trying to programmatically add a vertical UISlider to a UIView, with a variable height. This is what I have so far

```
int fullSize = [myBottle.barBottem intValue] - [myBottle.barTop intValue];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(200, 150,fullSize, 23);
    slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [slider setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    slider.minimumValue = 0.0;
    slider.maximumValue = fullSize;
    slider.continuous = YES;
    slider.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * -
                                                0.5);;
[self.view addSubview:slider];
```

My problem is that whenever fullSize is > 320, the slider wont appear. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this 
and make slider value method also

```
UISlider *loslider=[[UISlider alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 80, 200, 30)];

    [loslider addTarget:self action:@selector(slider_Action:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    [loslider setMaximumValue:100.0];
    [loslider setMinimumValue:0.0];
    [loslider setValue:0.0];
    [self.view addSubview:loslider];
```

then -(void)slider:Action

Answer (score 0):

The UIScrollView's frame should not be bigger than the containing UIView's rect. You should be altering the UIScrollView's contentSize, setting its height/width instead.

```
UIScrollView * scrollview ... ;
scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(newwidth,newheight);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code:

1.Create a new slider

```
-(IBAction)mySlider
{ 
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(20, 25, 200.0, 10.0);
    UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [slider setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    slider.minimumValue = 0.0;
    slider.maximumValue = 50.0;
    slider.continuous = YES;
    slider.value = 25.0;
    [self.view addSubview:slider];
}
```

2.For Slider Actions

```
-(void)sliderAction:(id)sender
{
    float value = [sender floatValue];
    NSLog(@"%@",value);
    //-- Do further actions
}
```